# Input Checkbox Doesn't Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 switches inside a Laravel Form where I already give default value as 0.
As soon as I submit, I got all values in my form, but those 2 switches.

I'm wondering if I did anything that I'm not suppose to.

---

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <label class="control-label">Multisite VPN</label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vpn" id="vpn" value="0">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 mb10">
    <label class="control-label">UPnP</label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="upnp" id="upnp" value="0">
</div>
```

---

## JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var vpn  = $('#vpn');
    var upnp  = $('#upnp');

    //Ativate the Switches
    vpn.bootstrapSwitch('size', 'mini');
    upnp.bootstrapSwitch('size', 'mini');


    vpn.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event) {
        if (vpn.is(':checked')) {
            vpn.val(1);
        } else {
            vpn.val(0);
        }
        console.log('vpn: ' + vpn.val());
    });

    upnp.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event) {
        if (upnp.is(':checked')) {
            upnp.val(1);
        } else {
            upnp.val(0);
        }
        console.log('upnp: ' + upnp.val());
    });

</script>
```

---

## Form

[image]

---

## inputs

```
array:17 [▼
  "_token" => "brXS4YGTGnD7QzkHuvbAyZsmSC8nUB9vxywB4bXK"
  "name" => "silver"
  "p_max_up" => "128"
  "p_max_down" => "128"
  "p_ip" => "111111111"
  "p_netmask" => "2222222222"
  "p_max_user" => "50"
  "p_dns" => "333333333"
  "p_dns2" => "4444444444"
  "g_max_up" => "128"
  "g_max_down" => "128"
  "g_ip" => "5000000"
  "g_netmask" => "6000000"
  "g_max_user" => "22"
  "g_dns" => "888888888"
  "g_dns2" => "9999999999"
  "g_portal" => "http://www.bunlongheng.com"
]
```

---

## If

I turn 2 those switches **ON**, I seems to get it

```
array:19 [▼
  "_token" => "brXS4YGTGnD7QzkHuvbAyZsmSC8nUB9vxywB4bXK"
  "name" => "silver"
  "vpn" => "1" <--------- HERE 
  "upnp" => "1" <--------- HERE
  "p_max_up" => "128"
  "p_max_down" => "128"
  "p_ip" => "111111111"
  "p_netmask" => "2222222222"
  "p_max_user" => "50"
  "p_dns" => "333333333"
  "p_dns2" => "4444444444"
  "g_max_up" => "128"
  "g_max_down" => "128"
  "g_ip" => "5000000"
  "g_netmask" => "6000000"
  "g_max_user" => "22"
  "g_dns" => "888888888"
  "g_dns2" => "9999999999"
  "g_portal" => "http://www.bunlongheng.com"
]
```

Why that `2` inputs submit only if the switches is `ON/True` ?

---

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When forms are submitted in HTML, unchecked checkboxes (which are the basis for your switches) are not transmitted.  Only checked checkboxes are transmitted with the form when it is submitted.  You could use hidden inputs and/or javascript to record if the checkboxes were ever checked or not and transmit those values instead.

Comment: Oh really, OMG, I guess, I'll do that, thanks for correcting me. :)

Comment: Since you've already got javascript functions that are executed when the switches are changed, I would create a hidden input to go along with each switch, and add a little code in your javascript functions to change the value of the hidden inputs when the switches are changed.